# node http2 requests with cookies

Tags: node.js, http2

Node http2 requests look like this:

```
const client = http2.connect('https://somehost.com')
const req = client.request( {
  ':path': '/some/path',
  ':method': 'GET',
  'header-name': 'header-value',
  'cookie': 'foo=bar'  
} )
```

It doesn't seem possible to send multiple cookie headers like this. Am I missing something? Note that the cookies should not get joined like in http/https headers.

Comment: you mean multiple cookies? if so, separate with `;`

Comment: Thanks but http2 cookies are sent as individual headers, not joined like http cookies.

Comment: my bad, the [docs](https://nodejs.org/api/http2.html#http2_headers_object) say use an array `'cookie': ['foo=bar', '...', '...']` if you want to use multiple

Comment: @Lawrence that looks promising, I'll give it a try.

Answer (score 0):

So my understanding is that if the client is HTTP/2 then you concatenate cookies with a semicolon like Lawrence said. Which is fine if the server is also HTTP/2, however if the server is HTTP/1.1 there will need to be some extra processing to concatenate them.

*If there are multiple Cookie header fields after
decompression, these MUST be concatenated into a single octet string
using the two-octet delimiter of 0x3B, 0x20 (the ASCII string "; ")*

Confirmed by the spec for HTTP2 https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc7540#section-8.1.2.5

Comment: I'm talking about HTTP2, not HTTP.

Comment: So I've updated my answer now, if that doesn't answer the question, could you explain why? Cheers

Answer (score 0):

As it is said in doc, duplicate cookie headers separated by `";"` and `set-cookie` should be array.

https://nodejs.org/api/http2.html#http2_headers_object

set-cookie is always an array. Duplicates are added to the array.
For duplicate cookie headers, the values are joined together with '; '.

```
const client = http2.connect('https://somehost.com')
const req = client.request( {
  ':path': '/some/path',
  ':method': 'GET',
  'header-name': 'header-value',
  'Set-Cookie': ['ting="tang; expires=0; path=/;"', 'wallawalla="bingbang; expires=123456789; path=/;"'],
} )
```